# How to display ASCII characters from 0 to 127 in decimal, octal and hexadecimal format using linux bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I have added the awk format to show the ascii character in bash script. But how can we actually display the ascii value in decimal, octal and hexadecimal in bash script?

```
awk -F":" '
BEGIN {
  print "## The chart below represents ASCII value from 0 to 127 in decimal, octal and hexadecimal format"
  printf "%-8s %-15s %-15s %-15s\n","Value","Decimal","Octal","Hexadecimal"
}
'
```

Desired Output:

```
Value Oct  Dec  Hex
!     041  33   21
```

Likewise for 0 to 127 ascii characters.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: The format you showed `"Decimal","Octal","Hexadecimal"` doesn't match the dired output you showed `Oct  Dec  Hex`. What exactly are you having problem with? Where are you stuck? Why does your awk script print "Decimal" string instead of "Oct", why not fix it? The goal is simple - loop a variable from 0 to 127 and then print it using different `printf` specifiers, it could be done really simple in awk. Do you want to do it in a bash script or in awk script?

Comment: You also might have some problems with non-printable characters.

Answer (score 4):

If your distro sources the man pages from the [man-pages project](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/) you can use the following

```
$ man ascii | sed -n '/Oct/,/Tables/p' | head -n -2
       Oct   Dec   Hex   Char                        Oct   Dec   Hex   Char
       ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
       000   0     00    NUL '\0' (null character)   100   64    40    @
       001   1     01    SOH (start of heading)      101   65    41    A
       002   2     02    STX (start of text)         102   66    42    B
       003   3     03    ETX (end of text)           103   67    43    C
       004   4     04    EOT (end of transmission)   104   68    44    D
       005   5     05    ENQ (enquiry)               105   69    45    E
       006   6     06    ACK (acknowledge)           106   70    46    F
       007   7     07    BEL '\a' (bell)             107   71    47    G
       010   8     08    BS  '\b' (backspace)        110   72    48    H
       011   9     09    HT  '\t' (horizontal tab)   111   73    49    I
       012   10    0A    LF  '\n' (new line)         112   74    4A    J
       013   11    0B    VT  '\v' (vertical tab)     113   75    4B    K
       014   12    0C    FF  '\f' (form feed)        114   76    4C    L
       015   13    0D    CR  '\r' (carriage ret)     115   77    4D    M
       016   14    0E    SO  (shift out)             116   78    4E    N
       017   15    0F    SI  (shift in)              117   79    4F    O
       020   16    10    DLE (data link escape)      120   80    50    P
       021   17    11    DC1 (device control 1)      121   81    51    Q
       022   18    12    DC2 (device control 2)      122   82    52    R
       023   19    13    DC3 (device control 3)      123   83    53    S
       024   20    14    DC4 (device control 4)      124   84    54    T
       025   21    15    NAK (negative ack.)         125   85    55    U
       026   22    16    SYN (synchronous idle)      126   86    56    V
       027   23    17    ETB (end of trans. blk)     127   87    57    W
       030   24    18    CAN (cancel)                130   88    58    X
       031   25    19    EM  (end of medium)         131   89    59    Y
       032   26    1A    SUB (substitute)            132   90    5A    Z
       033   27    1B    ESC (escape)                133   91    5B    [
       034   28    1C    FS  (file separator)        134   92    5C    \  '\\'
       035   29    1D    GS  (group separator)       135   93    5D    ]
       036   30    1E    RS  (record separator)      136   94    5E    ^
       037   31    1F    US  (unit separator)        137   95    5F    _
       040   32    20    SPACE                       140   96    60    `
       041   33    21    !                           141   97    61    a
       042   34    22    "                           142   98    62    b
       043   35    23    #                           143   99    63    c
       044   36    24    $                           144   100   64    d
       045   37    25    %                           145   101   65    e
       046   38    26    &                           146   102   66    f
       047   39    27    '                           147   103   67    g
       050   40    28    (                           150   104   68    h
       051   41    29    )                           151   105   69    i
       052   42    2A    *                           152   106   6A    j
       053   43    2B    +                           153   107   6B    k
       054   44    2C    ,                           154   108   6C    l
       055   45    2D    -                           155   109   6D    m
       056   46    2E    .                           156   110   6E    n

       057   47    2F    /                           157   111   6F    o
       060   48    30    0                           160   112   70    p
       061   49    31    1                           161   113   71    q
       062   50    32    2                           162   114   72    r
       063   51    33    3                           163   115   73    s
       064   52    34    4                           164   116   74    t
       065   53    35    5                           165   117   75    u
       066   54    36    6                           166   118   76    v
       067   55    37    7                           167   119   77    w
       070   56    38    8                           170   120   78    x
       071   57    39    9                           171   121   79    y
       072   58    3A    :                           172   122   7A    z
       073   59    3B    ;                           173   123   7B    {
       074   60    3C    <                           174   124   7C    |
       075   61    3D    =                           175   125   7D    }
       076   62    3E    >                           176   126   7E    ~
       077   63    3F    ?                           177   127   7F    DEL
$
```

Comment: That gets an UV for creative use of a man page in providing all the control character descriptions as well `:)`

Comment: It's a pity it doesn't work on Mac (the question is tagged `linux`, so that's OK)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin In reality, I just wanted to tell the OP that what they want is already there, ready to use, but I do appreciate your (plural) appreciation...

Comment: @WalterTross Has Mac no man pages about the different encodings?  I'm continuously using `man ascii` and I was continuously using `man iso-8859-1`,before Linux got better support for Unicode...

Comment: You can do a `man ascii` on Mac, but the output is completely different. The main information is essentially the same, of course, but, e.g., the description of control characters is missing. The output consists of three tables, for oct, hex and dec, and it would not be easy to format them into a single table.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another that provides a nice 4-column ASCII chart with special characters.

```
#!/bin/bash

special=(   "(nul)" "(soh)" "(stx)" "(etx)"
            "(eot)" "(enq)" "(ack)" "(bel)"
            "(bs)"  "(ht)"  "(nl)"  "(vt)"
            "(np)"  "(cr)"  "(so)"  "(si)"
            "(dle)" "(dc1)" "(dc2)" "(dc3)"
            "(dc4)" "(nak)" "(syn)" "(etb)"
            "(can)" "(em)"  "(sub)" "(esc)"
            "(fs)"  "(gs)"  "(rs)"  "(us)"
            "(sp)"  "(del)" )

## print heading
printf "Char  Dec  Oct  Hex | Char  Dec  Oct  Hex | Char  Dec  Oct  Hex | Char  Dec  Oct  Hex\n"
printf -- "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n"

## print table of chars
for ((i = 0; i < 32; i++)); do
    c1="${special[i]}"
    [ "$i" -gt 0 ] && c2="$(printf "\\$(printf '%03o' "$((i+32))")")" || c2="${special[32]}"
    c3="$(printf "\\$(printf '%03o' "$((i+64))")")"
    [ "$i" -lt 31 ] && c4="$(printf "\\$(printf '%03o' "$((i+96))")")" || c4="${special[33]}"
    printf "%-5s %3d %04o 0x%02x | %-5s %3d %04o 0x%02x | %-5s %3d %04o 0x%02x | %-5s %3d %04o 0x%02x\n" \
    "$c1" $i $i $i \
    "$c2" $((i+32)) $((i+32)) $((i+32)) \
    "$c3" $((i+64)) $((i+64)) $((i+64)) \
    "$c4" $((i+96)) $((i+96)) $((i+96))

done
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash asciichart.sh
Char  Dec  Oct  Hex | Char  Dec  Oct  Hex | Char  Dec  Oct  Hex | Char  Dec  Oct  Hex
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(nul)   0 0000 0x00 | (sp)   32 0040 0x20 | @      64 0100 0x40 | `      96 0140 0x60
(soh)   1 0001 0x01 | !      33 0041 0x21 | A      65 0101 0x41 | a      97 0141 0x61
(stx)   2 0002 0x02 | "      34 0042 0x22 | B      66 0102 0x42 | b      98 0142 0x62
(etx)   3 0003 0x03 | #      35 0043 0x23 | C      67 0103 0x43 | c      99 0143 0x63
(eot)   4 0004 0x04 | $      36 0044 0x24 | D      68 0104 0x44 | d     100 0144 0x64
(enq)   5 0005 0x05 | %      37 0045 0x25 | E      69 0105 0x45 | e     101 0145 0x65
(ack)   6 0006 0x06 | &      38 0046 0x26 | F      70 0106 0x46 | f     102 0146 0x66
(bel)   7 0007 0x07 | '      39 0047 0x27 | G      71 0107 0x47 | g     103 0147 0x67
(bs)    8 0010 0x08 | (      40 0050 0x28 | H      72 0110 0x48 | h     104 0150 0x68
(ht)    9 0011 0x09 | )      41 0051 0x29 | I      73 0111 0x49 | i     105 0151 0x69
(nl)   10 0012 0x0a | *      42 0052 0x2a | J      74 0112 0x4a | j     106 0152 0x6a
(vt)   11 0013 0x0b | +      43 0053 0x2b | K      75 0113 0x4b | k     107 0153 0x6b
(np)   12 0014 0x0c | ,      44 0054 0x2c | L      76 0114 0x4c | l     108 0154 0x6c
(cr)   13 0015 0x0d | -      45 0055 0x2d | M      77 0115 0x4d | m     109 0155 0x6d
(so)   14 0016 0x0e | .      46 0056 0x2e | N      78 0116 0x4e | n     110 0156 0x6e
(si)   15 0017 0x0f | /      47 0057 0x2f | O      79 0117 0x4f | o     111 0157 0x6f
(dle)  16 0020 0x10 | 0      48 0060 0x30 | P      80 0120 0x50 | p     112 0160 0x70
(dc1)  17 0021 0x11 | 1      49 0061 0x31 | Q      81 0121 0x51 | q     113 0161 0x71
(dc2)  18 0022 0x12 | 2      50 0062 0x32 | R      82 0122 0x52 | r     114 0162 0x72
(dc3)  19 0023 0x13 | 3      51 0063 0x33 | S      83 0123 0x53 | s     115 0163 0x73
(dc4)  20 0024 0x14 | 4      52 0064 0x34 | T      84 0124 0x54 | t     116 0164 0x74
(nak)  21 0025 0x15 | 5      53 0065 0x35 | U      85 0125 0x55 | u     117 0165 0x75
(syn)  22 0026 0x16 | 6      54 0066 0x36 | V      86 0126 0x56 | v     118 0166 0x76
(etb)  23 0027 0x17 | 7      55 0067 0x37 | W      87 0127 0x57 | w     119 0167 0x77
(can)  24 0030 0x18 | 8      56 0070 0x38 | X      88 0130 0x58 | x     120 0170 0x78
(em)   25 0031 0x19 | 9      57 0071 0x39 | Y      89 0131 0x59 | y     121 0171 0x79
(sub)  26 0032 0x1a | :      58 0072 0x3a | Z      90 0132 0x5a | z     122 0172 0x7a
(esc)  27 0033 0x1b | ;      59 0073 0x3b | [      91 0133 0x5b | {     123 0173 0x7b
(fs)   28 0034 0x1c | <      60 0074 0x3c | \      92 0134 0x5c | |     124 0174 0x7c
(gs)   29 0035 0x1d | =      61 0075 0x3d | ]      93 0135 0x5d | }     125 0175 0x7d
(rs)   30 0036 0x1e | >      62 0076 0x3e | ^      94 0136 0x5e | ~     126 0176 0x7e
(us)   31 0037 0x1f | ?      63 0077 0x3f | _      95 0137 0x5f | (del) 127 0177 0x7f
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the following in my `.bash_profile`:

```
command -v ascii &> /dev/null || function ascii { awk 'BEGIN {for (i = 32; i < 127; i++) printf "%3d 0x%02x %c\n", i, i, i}' | pr -t6 -w78; }
```

[image: ASCII table generated by ascii command]

I know it doesn't really answer your question, especially because it doesn't list the octal representation, but it's quite useful.

Please note that the characters with codes from 0 to 31 and 127 are control characters, so it makes no sense to display them.

Anyway, to match the format of your example (which is different from the format of your attempt), it seems that the following is what you need:

```
awk 'BEGIN {print "Value Oct  Dec  Hex"; for (i = 32; i < 127; i++) printf "%c     %03o  %-3d  %02x\n", i, i, i, i}'
```

You may change the range of the `for` to also display the control characters, but you will quickly see that the extra output is not of much use.

Answer (score 0):

Awk is not a particularly suitable tool for this. But here goes.

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    for (i=0; i<128; ++i)
        printf "%-8c %-15i %-15o %-15x\n", i, i, i, i 
    }' /dev/null
```

Many of the first 31 character codes are control characters which will mess up the tabular formatting.

Demo: https://ideone.com/mngMak

Answer (score 0):

Some of the arrays I made ahead of time, but this is what i use :

- The `"="` is shown as `"EQL"` instead because i'm usually too lazy to perfectly escape everything and simply use the equal sign `"="` as my delimiter for everything —- (*it's a lot easier to just find a custom way to escape the equal sign than deal with the plethora of quotation escaping rules*)

> 

```
mawk2x '{
    for(__ in dec2byte) {
        print \
        sprintf("%+04.f:%+04.f:%+04.f",\
         byte2dec[_=dec2byte[__]],\
         byte2sgned[_],\
         byte2neg[_]),\
        ("["(__==4^3-2-1?"EQL"\
            :(32<__)&&(__-2)<(3+2)^3\
                ?" "(_)" ":"_^_"))\
    ("|"byte2hex[_]"|"byte2oct[_]"]") } }' <<< '' | 

LC_ALL=C gsort -t= -k 1,1n | rs -t -c$'\n' -C= 0 2 | column -s= -t
```

> 

```
+000:+000:-256  [_^_|%00|\000]  +128:-128:-128  [_^_|%80|\200]
+001:+001:-255  [_^_|%01|\001]  +129:-127:-127  [_^_|%81|\201]
+002:+002:-254  [_^_|%02|\002]  +130:-126:-126  [_^_|%82|\202]
+003:+003:-253  [_^_|%03|\003]  +131:-125:-125  [_^_|%83|\203]
+004:+004:-252  [_^_|%04|\004]  +132:-124:-124  [_^_|%84|\204]
+005:+005:-251  [_^_|%05|\005]  +133:-123:-123  [_^_|%85|\205]
+006:+006:-250  [_^_|%06|\006]  +134:-122:-122  [_^_|%86|\206]
+007:+007:-249  [_^_|%07|\007]  +135:-121:-121  [_^_|%87|\207]
+008:+008:-248  [_^_|%08|\010]  +136:-120:-120  [_^_|%88|\210]
+009:+009:-247  [_^_|%09|\011]  +137:-119:-119  [_^_|%89|\211]
+010:+010:-246  [_^_|%0A|\012]  +138:-118:-118  [_^_|%8A|\212]
+011:+011:-245  [_^_|%0B|\013]  +139:-117:-117  [_^_|%8B|\213]
+012:+012:-244  [_^_|%0C|\014]  +140:-116:-116  [_^_|%8C|\214]
+013:+013:-243  [_^_|%0D|\015]  +141:-115:-115  [_^_|%8D|\215]
+014:+014:-242  [_^_|%0E|\016]  +142:-114:-114  [_^_|%8E|\216]
+015:+015:-241  [_^_|%0F|\017]  +143:-113:-113  [_^_|%8F|\217]

+016:+016:-240  [_^_|%10|\020]  +144:-112:-112  [_^_|%90|\220]
+017:+017:-239  [_^_|%11|\021]  +145:-111:-111  [_^_|%91|\221]
+018:+018:-238  [_^_|%12|\022]  +146:-110:-110  [_^_|%92|\222]
+019:+019:-237  [_^_|%13|\023]  +147:-109:-109  [_^_|%93|\223]
+020:+020:-236  [_^_|%14|\024]  +148:-108:-108  [_^_|%94|\224]
+021:+021:-235  [_^_|%15|\025]  +149:-107:-107  [_^_|%95|\225]
+022:+022:-234  [_^_|%16|\026]  +150:-106:-106  [_^_|%96|\226]
+023:+023:-233  [_^_|%17|\027]  +151:-105:-105  [_^_|%97|\227]
+024:+024:-232  [_^_|%18|\030]  +152:-104:-104  [_^_|%98|\230]
+025:+025:-231  [_^_|%19|\031]  +153:-103:-103  [_^_|%99|\231]
+026:+026:-230  [_^_|%1A|\032]  +154:-102:-102  [_^_|%9A|\232]
+027:+027:-229  [_^_|%1B|\033]  +155:-101:-101  [_^_|%9B|\233]
+028:+028:-228  [_^_|%1C|\034]  +156:-100:-100  [_^_|%9C|\234]
+029:+029:-227  [_^_|%1D|\035]  +157:-099:-099  [_^_|%9D|\235]
+030:+030:-226  [_^_|%1E|\036]  +158:-098:-098  [_^_|%9E|\236]
+031:+031:-225  [_^_|%1F|\037]  +159:-097:-097  [_^_|%9F|\237]

+032:+032:-224  [_^_|%20|\040]  +160:-096:-096  [_^_|%A0|\240]
+033:+033:-223  [ ! |%21|\041]  +161:-095:-095  [_^_|%A1|\241]
+034:+034:-222  [ " |%22|\042]  +162:-094:-094  [_^_|%A2|\242]
+035:+035:-221  [ # |%23|\043]  +163:-093:-093  [_^_|%A3|\243]
+036:+036:-220  [ $ |%24|\044]  +164:-092:-092  [_^_|%A4|\244]
+037:+037:-219  [ % |%25|\045]  +165:-091:-091  [_^_|%A5|\245]
+038:+038:-218  [ & |%26|\046]  +166:-090:-090  [_^_|%A6|\246]
+039:+039:-217  [ ' |%27|\047]  +167:-089:-089  [_^_|%A7|\247]
+040:+040:-216  [ ( |%28|\050]  +168:-088:-088  [_^_|%A8|\250]
+041:+041:-215  [ ) |%29|\051]  +169:-087:-087  [_^_|%A9|\251]
+042:+042:-214  [ * |%2A|\052]  +170:-086:-086  [_^_|%AA|\252]
+043:+043:-213  [ + |%2B|\053]  +171:-085:-085  [_^_|%AB|\253]
+044:+044:-212  [ , |%2C|\054]  +172:-084:-084  [_^_|%AC|\254]
+045:+045:-211  [ - |%2D|\055]  +173:-083:-083  [_^_|%AD|\255]
+046:+046:-210  [ . |%2E|\056]  +174:-082:-082  [_^_|%AE|\256]
+047:+047:-209  [ / |%2F|\057]  +175:-081:-081  [_^_|%AF|\257]

+048:+048:-208  [ 0 |%30|\060]  +176:-080:-080  [_^_|%B0|\260]
+049:+049:-207  [ 1 |%31|\061]  +177:-079:-079  [_^_|%B1|\261]
+050:+050:-206  [ 2 |%32|\062]  +178:-078:-078  [_^_|%B2|\262]
+051:+051:-205  [ 3 |%33|\063]  +179:-077:-077  [_^_|%B3|\263]
+052:+052:-204  [ 4 |%34|\064]  +180:-076:-076  [_^_|%B4|\264]
+053:+053:-203  [ 5 |%35|\065]  +181:-075:-075  [_^_|%B5|\265]
+054:+054:-202  [ 6 |%36|\066]  +182:-074:-074  [_^_|%B6|\266]
+055:+055:-201  [ 7 |%37|\067]  +183:-073:-073  [_^_|%B7|\267]
+056:+056:-200  [ 8 |%38|\070]  +184:-072:-072  [_^_|%B8|\270]
+057:+057:-199  [ 9 |%39|\071]  +185:-071:-071  [_^_|%B9|\271]
+058:+058:-198  [ : |%3A|\072]  +186:-070:-070  [_^_|%BA|\272]
+059:+059:-197  [ ; |%3B|\073]  +187:-069:-069  [_^_|%BB|\273]
+060:+060:-196  [ < |%3C|\074]  +188:-068:-068  [_^_|%BC|\274]
+061:+061:-195  [EQL|%3D|\075]  +189:-067:-067  [_^_|%BD|\275]
+062:+062:-194  [ > |%3E|\076]  +190:-066:-066  [_^_|%BE|\276]
+063:+063:-193  [ ? |%3F|\077]  +191:-065:-065  [_^_|%BF|\277]

+064:+064:-192  [ @ |%40|\100]  +192:-064:-064  [_^_|%C0|\300]
+065:+065:-191  [ A |%41|\101]  +193:-063:-063  [_^_|%C1|\301]
+066:+066:-190  [ B |%42|\102]  +194:-062:-062  [_^_|%C2|\302]
+067:+067:-189  [ C |%43|\103]  +195:-061:-061  [_^_|%C3|\303]
+068:+068:-188  [ D |%44|\104]  +196:-060:-060  [_^_|%C4|\304]
+069:+069:-187  [ E |%45|\105]  +197:-059:-059  [_^_|%C5|\305]
+070:+070:-186  [ F |%46|\106]  +198:-058:-058  [_^_|%C6|\306]
+071:+071:-185  [ G |%47|\107]  +199:-057:-057  [_^_|%C7|\307]
+072:+072:-184  [ H |%48|\110]  +200:-056:-056  [_^_|%C8|\310]
+073:+073:-183  [ I |%49|\111]  +201:-055:-055  [_^_|%C9|\311]
+074:+074:-182  [ J |%4A|\112]  +202:-054:-054  [_^_|%CA|\312]
+075:+075:-181  [ K |%4B|\113]  +203:-053:-053  [_^_|%CB|\313]
+076:+076:-180  [ L |%4C|\114]  +204:-052:-052  [_^_|%CC|\314]
+077:+077:-179  [ M |%4D|\115]  +205:-051:-051  [_^_|%CD|\315]
+078:+078:-178  [ N |%4E|\116]  +206:-050:-050  [_^_|%CE|\316]
+079:+079:-177  [ O |%4F|\117]  +207:-049:-049  [_^_|%CF|\317]

+080:+080:-176  [ P |%50|\120]  +208:-048:-048  [_^_|%D0|\320]
+081:+081:-175  [ Q |%51|\121]  +209:-047:-047  [_^_|%D1|\321]
+082:+082:-174  [ R |%52|\122]  +210:-046:-046  [_^_|%D2|\322]
+083:+083:-173  [ S |%53|\123]  +211:-045:-045  [_^_|%D3|\323]
+084:+084:-172  [ T |%54|\124]  +212:-044:-044  [_^_|%D4|\324]
+085:+085:-171  [ U |%55|\125]  +213:-043:-043  [_^_|%D5|\325]
+086:+086:-170  [ V |%56|\126]  +214:-042:-042  [_^_|%D6|\326]
+087:+087:-169  [ W |%57|\127]  +215:-041:-041  [_^_|%D7|\327]
+088:+088:-168  [ X |%58|\130]  +216:-040:-040  [_^_|%D8|\330]
+089:+089:-167  [ Y |%59|\131]  +217:-039:-039  [_^_|%D9|\331]
+090:+090:-166  [ Z |%5A|\132]  +218:-038:-038  [_^_|%DA|\332]
+091:+091:-165  [ [ |%5B|\133]  +219:-037:-037  [_^_|%DB|\333]
+092:+092:-164  [ \ |%5C|\134]  +220:-036:-036  [_^_|%DC|\334]
+093:+093:-163  [ ] |%5D|\135]  +221:-035:-035  [_^_|%DD|\335]
+094:+094:-162  [ ^ |%5E|\136]  +222:-034:-034  [_^_|%DE|\336]
+095:+095:-161  [ _ |%5F|\137]  +223:-033:-033  [_^_|%DF|\337]

+096:+096:-160  [ ` |%60|\140]  +224:-032:-032  [_^_|%E0|\340]
+097:+097:-159  [ a |%61|\141]  +225:-031:-031  [_^_|%E1|\341]
+098:+098:-158  [ b |%62|\142]  +226:-030:-030  [_^_|%E2|\342]
+099:+099:-157  [ c |%63|\143]  +227:-029:-029  [_^_|%E3|\343]
+100:+100:-156  [ d |%64|\144]  +228:-028:-028  [_^_|%E4|\344]
+101:+101:-155  [ e |%65|\145]  +229:-027:-027  [_^_|%E5|\345]
+102:+102:-154  [ f |%66|\146]  +230:-026:-026  [_^_|%E6|\346]
+103:+103:-153  [ g |%67|\147]  +231:-025:-025  [_^_|%E7|\347]
+104:+104:-152  [ h |%68|\150]  +232:-024:-024  [_^_|%E8|\350]
+105:+105:-151  [ i |%69|\151]  +233:-023:-023  [_^_|%E9|\351]
+106:+106:-150  [ j |%6A|\152]  +234:-022:-022  [_^_|%EA|\352]
+107:+107:-149  [ k |%6B|\153]  +235:-021:-021  [_^_|%EB|\353]
+108:+108:-148  [ l |%6C|\154]  +236:-020:-020  [_^_|%EC|\354]
+109:+109:-147  [ m |%6D|\155]  +237:-019:-019  [_^_|%ED|\355]
+110:+110:-146  [ n |%6E|\156]  +238:-018:-018  [_^_|%EE|\356]
+111:+111:-145  [ o |%6F|\157]  +239:-017:-017  [_^_|%EF|\357]

+112:+112:-144  [ p |%70|\160]  +240:-016:-016  [_^_|%F0|\360]
+113:+113:-143  [ q |%71|\161]  +241:-015:-015  [_^_|%F1|\361]
+114:+114:-142  [ r |%72|\162]  +242:-014:-014  [_^_|%F2|\362]
+115:+115:-141  [ s |%73|\163]  +243:-013:-013  [_^_|%F3|\363]
+116:+116:-140  [ t |%74|\164]  +244:-012:-012  [_^_|%F4|\364]
+117:+117:-139  [ u |%75|\165]  +245:-011:-011  [_^_|%F5|\365]
+118:+118:-138  [ v |%76|\166]  +246:-010:-010  [_^_|%F6|\366]
+119:+119:-137  [ w |%77|\167]  +247:-009:-009  [_^_|%F7|\367]
+120:+120:-136  [ x |%78|\170]  +248:-008:-008  [_^_|%F8|\370]
+121:+121:-135  [ y |%79|\171]  +249:-007:-007  [_^_|%F9|\371]
+122:+122:-134  [ z |%7A|\172]  +250:-006:-006  [_^_|%FA|\372]
+123:+123:-133  [ { |%7B|\173]  +251:-005:-005  [_^_|%FB|\373]
+124:+124:-132  [ | |%7C|\174]  +252:-004:-004  [_^_|%FC|\374]
+125:+125:-131  [ } |%7D|\175]  +253:-003:-003  [_^_|%FD|\375]
+126:+126:-130  [ ~ |%7E|\176]  +254:-002:-002  [_^_|%FE|\376]
+127:+127:-129  [_^_|%7F|\177]  +255:-001:-001  [_^_|%FF|\377]
```

if u don't need the fanciness, the `jot + od` does plenty  :

> ```
> jot -n -s '' -c - 0 255 | od -bac -t x1u1 | lgp3 5
> ```

```
0000000   000 001 002 003 004 005 006 007 010 011 012 013 014 015 016 017
         nul soh stx etx eot enq ack bel  bs  ht  nl  vt  ff  cr  so  si
          \0 001 002 003 004 005 006  \a  \b  \t  \n  \v  \f  \r 016 017
           00  01  02  03  04  05  06  07  08  09  0a  0b  0c  0d  0e  0f
            0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15

0000020   020 021 022 023 024 025 026 027 030 031 032 033 034 035 036 037
         dle dc1 dc2 dc3 dc4 nak syn etb can  em sub esc  fs  gs  rs  us
         020 021 022 023 024 025 026 027 030 031 032 033 034 035 036 037
           10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  1a  1b  1c  1d  1e  1f
           16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31

0000040   040 041 042 043 044 045 046 047 050 051 052 053 054 055 056 057
          sp   !   "   #   $   %   &   '   (   )   *   +   ,   -   .   /
               !   "   #   $   %   &   '   (   )   *   +   ,   -   .   /
           20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  2a  2b  2c  2d  2e  2f
           32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47

0000060   060 061 062 063 064 065 066 067 070 071 072 073 074 075 076 077
           0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   :   ;   <   =   >   ?
           0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   :   ;   <   =   >   ?
           30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  3a  3b  3c  3d  3e  3f
           48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63

0000100   100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117
           @   A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N   O
           @   A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N   O
           40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  4a  4b  4c  4d  4e  4f
           64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79

0000120   120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137
           P   Q   R   S   T   U   V   W   X   Y   Z   [   \   ]   ^   _
           P   Q   R   S   T   U   V   W   X   Y   Z   [   \   ]   ^   _
           50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  5a  5b  5c  5d  5e  5f
           80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95

0000140   140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157
           `   a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k   l   m   n   o
           `   a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k   l   m   n   o
           60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  6a  6b  6c  6d  6e  6f
           96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111

0000160   160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177
           p   q   r   s   t   u   v   w   x   y   z   {   |   }   ~ del
           p   q   r   s   t   u   v   w   x   y   z   {   |   }   ~ 177
           70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  7a  7b  7c  7d  7e  7f
          112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127

0000200   200 201 202 203 204 205 206 207 210 211 212 213 214 215 216 217
          80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  8a  8b  8c  8d  8e  8f
         200 201 202 203 204 205 206 207 210 211 212 213 214 215 216 217
           80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  8a  8b  8c  8d  8e  8f
          128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143

0000220   220 221 222 223 224 225 226 227 230 231 232 233 234 235 236 237
          90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99  9a  9b  9c  9d  9e  9f
         220 221 222 223 224 225 226 227 230 231 232 233 234 235 236 237
           90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99  9a  9b  9c  9d  9e  9f
          144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159

0000240   240 241 242 243 244 245 246 247 250 251 252 253 254 255 256 257
           ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?
         240 241 242 243 244 245 246 247 250 251 252 253 254 255 256 257
           a0  a1  a2  a3  a4  a5  a6  a7  a8  a9  aa  ab  ac  ad  ae  af
          160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175

0000260   260 261 262 263 264 265 266 267 270 271 272 273 274 275 276 277
           ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?
         260 261 262 263 264 265 266 267 270 271 272 273 274 275 276 277
           b0  b1  b2  b3  b4  b5  b6  b7  b8  b9  ba  bb  bc  bd  be  bf
          176 177 178 179 180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 191

0000300   300 301 302 303 304 305 306 307 310 311 312 313 314 315 316 317
           ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?
         300 301 302 303 304 305 306 307 310 311 312 313 314 315 316 317
           c0  c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6  c7  c8  c9  ca  cb  cc  cd  ce  cf
          192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200 201 202 203 204 205 206 207

0000320   320 321 322 323 324 325 326 327 330 331 332 333 334 335 336 337
           ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?
         320 321 322 323 324 325 326 327 330 331 332 333 334 335 336 337
           d0  d1  d2  d3  d4  d5  d6  d7  d8  d9  da  db  dc  dd  de  df
          208 209 210 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 220 221 222 223

0000340   340 341 342 343 344 345 346 347 350 351 352 353 354 355 356 357
           ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?
         340 341 342 343 344 345 346 347 350 351 352 353 354 355 356 357
           e0  e1  e2  e3  e4  e5  e6  e7  e8  e9  ea  eb  ec  ed  ee  ef
          224 225 226 227 228 229 230 231 232 233 234 235 236 237 238 239

0000360   360 361 362 363 364 365 366 367 370 371 372 373 374 375 376 377
           ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?
         360 361 362 363 364 365 366 367 370 371 372 373 374 375 376 377
           f0  f1  f2  f3  f4  f5  f6  f7  f8  f9  fa  fb  fc  fd  fe  ff
          240 241 242 243 244 245 246 247 248 249 250 251 252 253 254 255

0000400
```